# Partitioning MongoDB Atlas Data into Realms

Tags: mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am working through partitioning of MongoDB Atlas data into Realms to use the Realm sync feature for mobile devices.  For reference, I am looking at the information provided here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/partitioning/#partitioning

When sharing data between users, MongoDB proposes the following partition strategy:

> **User Realms:** If your application stores data privately for each
> individual user, you could create an owner_id field containing a
> specific user ID for every document. Selecting the owner_id field as
> your partition key would partition your database into realms
> corresponding to individual users.
>
> **Team Realms:** If your application
> shares resources across teams, you could create a teams collection
> that maps user IDs to team IDs. You could then create a team_id field
> containing a specific team ID for every document you want to sync.
> Selecting the team_id field as your partition key would partition your
> database into realms containing data for entire teams.
>
> **Public Realms:**
> It’s often helpful to store read-only data viewable to all users; for
> this kind of use case, you can define a special partition value in
> your permissions, such as PUBLIC, that all users sync with read
> permissions only.

So that all makes sense, but what about documents that a user creates and then shares with one or more other users?  If I have a `sharedWith` field that points to other `user_id's`, and I make that the partition key, then it could work but all the documentation seems to caution against updating the value of these partition keys for risk of triggering a client reset.

Through the research I've done via google, StackOverflow etc., I can only find examples that assume the data stays static but I need to allow users to add and remove the sharing permissions.  Any suggestions on how this might be approached?

Comment: If you're sharing an object with others, that would be considered a 'team' so that strategy works. If it's open to all others then it would be considered public. If you allow other users to access your realm, that would be user but others have access privileges. So as you can see, without understanding the entire use case it would very difficult to provide a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  The use case is that users can randomly share their documents with one or more other users.  The sharing isn’t linked to specific lists of users (e.g. team ‘aaa’ of users), rather they can, at any stage in the lifecycle of a document, add users to share with and likewise remove a user that the document is shared with.  The share privileges can be either read or write.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Realm but looking at that documentation I'd say for documents you would use the public partitioning with document id as the prefix, similarly to how salespeople are handled.

Then I imagine you'd need to have a server-side endpoint for sharing which would write permitted document ids into all of the users that have access to those documents (the server-side endpoint will be able to see the complete view of data, not limited to any one user).

Comment: Thank you but I don’t think that would work.  Whilst you can assign read/write permissions at document level, the partition key would automatically sync all data in that Realm down to client devices which is what I am trying to avoid.